# Is there a way to extract data from an HTML table on another web page?

Tags: html

I was curious if there was a way the computer could read that data and shoot it into a computer program so you could use that data. For example, if I could go to ESPN's site, view the league standings and send the records to my code, i guess is that possible. I know some sites have APIs you can use, but the site I would use it on does not...

Comment: Nopes. Not possible. CORS.

Comment: If you don't have public API you can take a loot at [Web Scraping](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

Comment: You can make a request to your server which makes a request to ESPN's server to fetch the data.

Comment: With client-side stuff: No. With server-side stuff: Yes, just launch your own HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this to implement data scraping for machine learning purposes with Beautiful Soup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in Python. It works 'beautifully' by grabbing the html of the page and turning it into an object which you can then work with and search for certain tags, say, table tags.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is through web scraping which is pretty advanced if you're not tech savy. This is going to require a lot more than HTML. Maybe try this out if you don't want to build your own:

http://webscraper.io/